# Slim Framework v3, getting JSON data via POST issue

Tags: php, json, slim, slim-3

I'm am using the Slim Framework v3 and have some problems with accessing the JSON data I'm sending from a browser client to my REST API.

Currently I'm using `$request->getParsedBody();` to access the data, but all it returns is a string and I don't want to parse it, because I think there's a better solution for this problem.

Here's what is sent by the client:

```
$data = array ();
$data ["key1"] = "value1";
$data ["key2"] = "value2";
$data ["key3"] = "value3";
$data = json_encode ( $data );
```

This produces `{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}`

What happens on the server?

```
$app->post ( '/somePath', function ($request, $response) {
    $body = $request->getParsedBody();
    var_dump($body);
    return $response;
});
```

The `var_dump();` is producing the following output:

```
string(86) "array(1) {
  ["{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
"
```

As you can see, `$request->getParsedBody();` is returning a string. 
Is there any better way to do this?

I already tried to use `$request->getBody();`, but that returns an object of the type Slim\Http\RequestBody and has only protected variables. I haven't found any function to access these protected variables.

Please remember that I'm using Slim v3, they have changed a lot of things from v2.

If there is no better way, do you have suggestions how to parse it the best way?

Comment: You need to post your data with Content-Type: application/json header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As reported by the Slim 3 docs:

> JSON requests are converted into associative arrays with json_decode($input, true).

So getParsedBody is definitely the way to go.
Instead, have you check the request type set by your client? It should be `application/json` in order to make the Slim request object do the correct interpretation of the raw body.

eg:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: Okay, the output looks better, but it is still a string `string(115) "array(3) {
  ["key1"]=>
  string(6) "value1"
  ["key2"]=>
  string(6) "value2"
  ["key3"]=>
  string(6) "value3"
}
"`

Comment: Can you please post the resulting string?

Comment: Updated the first comment

Comment: Nevermind, my bad, I sent the request to the server, did a `var_dump()`, sent it back to the client and did `var_dump()` again. It's working now. Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear that. ;)

Comment: I lost so much time trying to find why my data wasn't appearing in my request, thank you so much @LuigiPressello

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the problem is in the data that you're getting from the client. You're receiving a sort of `var_dump` or `var_export` output as the user in this case. According with the data that you receive, I would search something like this in your client code:

```
<?php var_export([json_encode($data) => '',],true);
```

On the server side the body can't be parsed because it's not a correct JSON string.

Comment: I don't modify the data on my client, expect for what I already posted. I send it with: `curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );`

Comment: Can you update your question with the client side code? From my point of view, the data is being modified in some point. Also, as @LuigiPresello  said, check that you're sending your data with the correct content type headers (this will help the framework to do a better data format conversion)